# Dict from JSON object not writing out to file using DictWriter

Tags: python, json, csv, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm parsing a jira database using the `oauth2` library, receiving a bytes object back that I'm decoding with `UTF-8`, and then using `json.loads` to return the resulting string object as a dictionary.  I'm then trying to write it out to a flat file using `DictWriter`, but it's returning the following error:

```
File "/Users/mharris/PycharmProjects/CodeRepo/jira_oauth.py", line 206, in <module>
    writer.writerows(data)
  File "/Users/mharris/anaconda/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 156, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
  File "/Users/mharris/anaconda/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 150, in <genexpr>
    return (rowdict.get(key, self.restval) for key in self.fieldnames)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I'm doing a `print(type(data))` to verify that it is indeed a dictionary.
Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
with psycopg2.connect(
        host=settings.REDSHIFT_HOST,
        port=settings.REDSHIFT_PORT,
        database=settings.REDSHIFT_DATABASE,
        user=settings.REDSHIFT_USER,
        password=settings.REDSHIFT_PASS) as conn:

    cur = conn.cursor()

    get_cols = '''
    SELECT *
    FROM ods_jira.staging_jira_issues
    LIMIT 10
    '''

    cur.execute(get_cols)
    colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

    max_res = 1000
    data_url = data_url_base + mk_data_endpoint(max_res, start_at)

with gzip.open('jira_data.txt.gz', 'w') as outf:
    writer = DictWriter(outf,
                        delimiter='|',
                        quotechar='"',
                        fieldnames=colnames,
                        extrasaction='ignore')

    for cycle in range(1):
        response, content = client.request(data_url, 'GET')
        if response['status'] != '200':
            raise Exception('Unable to access page, code was: ',
                            response['status'])

        str_resp = content.decode('utf-8')
        print(type(str_resp))
        data = json.loads(str_resp)
        print(type(data))
        writer.writerows(data)

        start_at += 1000
```

Answer (score 1):

writerows expects a list of dictionaries. If you have one dictionary, use writerow.

```
str_resp = content.decode('utf-8')
print(type(str_resp))
data = json.loads(str_resp)
print(type(data))
writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: New error is:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mharris/PycharmProjects/CodeRepo/jira_oauth.py", line 205, in <module>
    writer.writerow(data)
  File "/Users/mharris/anaconda/lib/python3.5/csv.py", line 153, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/Users/mharris/anaconda/lib/python3.5/gzip.py", line 258, in write
    data = memoryview(data)
TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: So it looks like it's because I'm doing stuff with gzip.

Comment: try with : with gzip.open('jira_data.txt.gz', 'wt')

Comment: Also, you should be explicitly passing `newline=''` to `gzip.open` (and any file opened for read or write for use with the `csv` module) to prevent line ending translation, letting the `csv` module handle it properly in an OS independent way.